# Can we trigger a particular activity of a specific execution of a state machine built using AWS Step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Using GetActivityTask API provides access to activity of any random one execution of state machine already running. Is it possible to get a particular activity of a particular execution ?

Suppose my state machine is -

```
Start -> A -> B -> C -> End

Execution1 : Start1 -> A1 -> B1 -> C1 -> End
Execution2 : Start2 -> A2 -> B2 -> C2 -> End
```

Can I get access to A1 particularly if I have executionId (Execution1) and ActivityARN name (A) ? If not why does AWS do not allow this.

Requirement : I want to create APIs like

```
1> SubmitRequest - 
Input - Some input
Output - RequestId
```

Which starts a particular execution of state machine and returns after activity A is executed. Behind the scene machine runs B

```
2> GetC -
Input - RequestId
Output -  If the state machine is in correct state to call C we should run C and provide its output otherwise throw an exception.
```

So basically want to use AWS step function to manage state for my application and if an API is called in incorrect state throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the [GetExecutionHistory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html) API call should do what you need. It will let you see the execution status of each state and activity and see the input and output of each.